# How would I use Xeon Phi with OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl, xeon-phi

So I just got myself a Xeon Phi and now Im wondering how could I use it with OpenCL because most of the tutorial uses OpenMP.
If I change target device to the Xeon Phi and run the kernel will it work? Do I need any other library than the Intel SDK for OpenCL(v14.2).

Comment: Using the Phi as offload or host? Quick search appears that OpenCL doesn't support the Phi for host, not sure about offloading though. Since the Phi has been discontinued, not sure if OpenCL would bother adding support for it...

Comment: @ChrisMM its a 5110p so it's not going to be the host but an offload ( those standalone are just too expensive )

Comment: Using these is rather difficult with the buggy and deprecated driver support. Can you run `micinfo` in the terminal? Usually you first `ssh mic0` into the coprocessor and there it should be detected by `clinfo`, similar to an Intel server CPU once the OpenCL runtime is installed.